# duplicate every second element in a array

Tags: arrays, duplicates, listobject

my code isnt working for all junit tests. input is an array and output is
an array where every second element is duplicatet. for example [1;2;3;4;5] ->[1;2;2;3;4;4;5]
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
public Listobject<T>[] duplicateEverySecondElement(Listobject<T>[] array){
if(array != null && array.length > 0){
    int n = array.length - 1;
    if((array.length % 2) == 0){
       for(int i = (array.length + array.length / 2) - 1; i > 0; i -= 3){
           array[i] = array[n];
           array[i - 1] = array[n];
           array[i - 2] = array[n - 1];
           n -= 2;
       }
       return array;
    }
    else 
    for(int i = (array.length + array.length / 2) - 1; i > 0; i -= 3){
        array[i] = array[n];
        array[i - 1] = array[n - 1];
        array[i - 2] = array[n - 1];
        n -= 2;
    }
    return array;
}
else return array;
```

}

Comment: Can you give a example of a test where it fails?

Comment: One of the four tests is dynamicTest_duplicate_array_elements(array.insert.tests_duplicateEverySecondElement.duplicateEverySecondElement_Array_Test)

Comment: Ah, I meant actual data, not code - what is input to the function, the expected output and the actual output.

Answer (score -1):

I found the logic a bit hard to follow making the bug hard to find. Perhaps you would want to use a boolean=true/false to flag when you are on a second element, and when this boolean is true you can have output duplicated.

Comment: at first I tried to go from the list upwards. But i had too create too many temporary valuebels to save the elements i overwrote. So I tried too go backwards from array[(array.length + array.lengeth / 2 )- 1] which should be the last place in the new array. I added two for statements. The first if the last element of array should be doubled and the second if not

Comment: The problem with the code is the logic, its really confusing and I believe you can acheive your desired result alot easier. Use just one loop, and throw in a boolean to track when to duplicate rather than checking for when its odd or even using the %. Start the boolean equal to false, and switch it at the end of your loop. When the boolean is true, just have the data sent twice to your new array.